# Android Litsview not refreshing after delete row

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter

I have a listview. In the row items I have a button to erase a row. When clicked I execute a volley request to my remote server and if the response  was ok, I proceed to delete the row.

The problem is that sometimes I get a positive response from volley request saying my row was deleted on server. But without to do a new refresh from server, my code to delete the row from adapter sometimes doesn´t works.

Other times, the adapter delete the row and  refresh normally.

Is it a problem to call the procedure to delete the row into volley request response?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ListviewAgendaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ObjectAgenda> {
    private int selected = -1;
    ArrayList<ObjectAgenda> items;
    private Activity context;


    public ListviewAgendaAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ObjectAgenda> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.singlerowagenda, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void add(ObjectAgenda oa){
        this.items.add(oa);
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<ObjectAgenda> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void select(int position) {
        this.selected = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectAgenda getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void deleteRowFromUi(int position) {
        this.items.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ObjectAgenda o = items.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerowagenda, null);// e' preciso fazer o inflate pois a view nao ainda nao esta em activity alguma
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvIndice = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvindice);
            holder.tvNomeMed = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvnomemed);
            holder.butdesmarca = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.butdesmarcar);
            holder.butdesmarca.setTag(position);
            holder.butdesmarca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    desmarca_agenda(index);
                }
            });

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(selected != -1 && position == selected) {
            vi.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }else vi.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor( R.color.white));

        holder.tvIndice.setText(String.valueOf(o.getIndice()));
        holder.tvNomeMed.setText(o.getNome_med());
        return vi;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvIndice, tvNomeMed;
        Button butdesmarca;

    }

private void desmarca_agenda(final Integer position) {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
                ja.put(indice);
                String mot=textMot.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mot)) mot="Não especificado";
                ja.put(mot);
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonBody.put("_parameters", ja);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String s = "";
                        try {
                            JSONArray LResult = response.getJSONArray("result");
                            s = LResult.get(0).toString();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (s.equals("true")) {
                            deleteRowFromUi(position.intValue());
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                Common.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jr, "jreq"); 

            }
```

Here is my Fragment using the adapter:

```
public class AgendaMedFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = AgendaMedFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    ListviewAgendaAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<ObjectAgenda> items;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agendamedfrag, null);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_cons);
        View v = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_cons);
        listView.setEmptyView(v);
        items = new ArrayList<ObjectAgenda>();
        adapter = new ListviewAgendaAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button but_data_execute= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.but_data_agenda_execute);
        but_data_execute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                execute_get_agendamentos();
            }
        });

        execute_get_agendamentos();
        return view;
    }



    private void parseJSONResponseAgendamentos(JSONObject response) {
        try {

            JSONArray LResult = response.getJSONArray("result");
            String s = LResult.get(0).toString();
            JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(s);

            items.clear();
            for (int count = 0; count < entries.length(); count++) {
                JSONObject anEntry = entries.getJSONObject(count);

                String email = Common.getInstance().obag.getEmail();
                String senha = Common.getInstance().obag.getSenha();
                items.add(new ObjectAgenda(email, senha));
            }
            adapter.setData(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void execute_get_agendamentos() {
        String url = Common.getServerURL() + "\"ag_get_ag\"";

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        String email = "email"
        String senha = "pass"
        ja.put(email);
        ja.put(senha);
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("_parameters", ja);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parseJSONResponseAgendamentos(response);

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Common.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jr, "jreq");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think removing         notifyDataSetInvalidated(); would solve this problem

Comment: I already use it at "deleteRowFromUi". It doesn´t solve the problem.

Comment: My orginal code was: items.remove(position.intValue());
                                   notifyDataSetChanged();  but I had the same problem. Then I add notifyDataSetInvalidated(); and the problem continues.

Comment: You only need notifyDataSetChanged and also you are not using this correctly. You are trying to call a local variable by using this when you want the global variable "items" you should remove "this"

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayAdapter` and your class-reference to `items` are out of sync, probably because you called your `setData(List<ObjectAgenda>)` method.

If you really need the class-reference to your data, you need to change a couple things.

```
public void setData(ArrayList<ObjectAgenda> items) {
    super.clear();

    for(ObjectAgenda a : items)
        super.add(a);

    this.items = items;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And also:

```
public void deleteRowFromUi(int position) {
    super.remove(getItem(position));

    this.items.remove(position);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Personally, though, I would get rid of your class-reference to items entirely and only use the ArrayAdapter's built-in methods, as there's really no reason for you to do that... It's just extra work keeping the references in sync.

Comment: Sorry, with these changes my listview is not populated. I have an empty listview.

Comment: I have a volley request to my server. On reponse ok, I do the next to populate the listview:             items.clear();
            for (int count = 0; count < entries.length(); count++) {
                JSONObject anEntry = entries.getJSONObject(count);
                String email = Common.getInstance().obag.getEmail();
                items.add(new ObjectAgenda(email);            }
            }
            adapter.setData(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You should checkout the [ArrayAdapter code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) and look at the `List<T> mObjects` variable. You should notice that, when combined with your adapter's implementation, you're actually working with 2 lists that are out of sync with each other, instead of the single list that backs the adapter like you think you are.

Comment: OK, I checked my fragment using the adapter I am unable to find something wrong. I will post it in my question.

Comment: If you can look at in my fragment code that uses the adapter, I will appreciate. The problem is intermittent, sometimes it happens another not

Comment: I actually just noticed your overridden `ArrayAdapter.add(ObjectAgenda)` method. You need to call super.add() from within there or, better yet, remove that method entirely.